# Oracle SQL - Reading delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm developing a command in Oracle SQL using a table that has that type of row:

```
company=1&product=12588&version=1
```

For my command, I need the product number and version of each row, but separated by columns.

My first question: How can I read only the product number, using something different of REGEXP_SUBSTR

My second question: What is the best way to create a new column to show the version without duplicate the line?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You can use INSTR() to locate the $ characters.

Comment: The alternatives to using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` will make the solution *much* more difficult to read and prove correct.

Comment: Of course, your problem is the result of an abysmally bad design.  A given column should have one single, atomic value.  Not only do you have multiple values in a column, but you have multiple _types_ of data in a single column.  Whoever came up with that design is in serious need  of education in the very fundamentals of relational database design.

Answer (score 1):

If data really is that simple, regular expressions make code rather simple. Way simpler than `SUBSTR + INSTR` option. Why don't you want to use regex? Because it is *evil*, or ...?

- sample data in lines #1 - 4
- `product`: take the 2nd numeric value from the column
- `version`: take the last numeric value from the column

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'company=1&product=12588&version=1' from dual union all
  3     select 'company=2&product=52361&version=4' from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) as product,
  7    regexp_substr(col, '\d+$')      as version
  8  from test;

COL                               PRODUCT    VERSION
--------------------------------- ---------- ----------
company=1&product=12588&version=1 12588      1
company=2&product=52361&version=4 52361      4

SQL>
```

---

As of

> What is the best way to create a new column to show the version without duplicate the line?

I have no idea what that means. "Without duplicate the line"? Which line? Which duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can use sql below by combining only the ** substr ** and ** instr ** functions.
This solution takes advantage of the four and last parameter of the **instr** function.

```sql
select your_column
, substr(your_column
          , instr(your_column, '=', 1, 1) + 1
          , instr(your_column, '&', 1, 1) - instr(your_column, '=', 1, 1) - 1 
   ) company
, substr(your_column
          , instr(your_column, '=', 1, 2) + 1
          , instr(your_column, '&', 1, 2) - instr(your_column, '=', 1, 2) - 1 
   ) product
, substr(your_column
          , instr(your_column, '=', 1, 3) + 1 
  ) version
from (
  select 'company=1&product=12588&version=1' your_column from dual union all
  select 'company=2&product=52361&version=4' your_column from dual
) Your_data
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b8296365d3f18847bed37fcd8fe70e0)

But, I'm not sure I understood your second question correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Worked to me!

Comment: You're welcome.